# Why is there no .chrome option for webdriver-manager?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I installed all webdrivers (webdrivermanager, webdriver-manager and webdriver_manager) with pip, but when I enter `from webdriver_manager.c`, the intellisense only suggests `config` and `commands`. If I enter `.chrome` it suggests creating a new function. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I'm using PyCharm, Windows 10, selenium 4.9.0, and python 3.11.3.

Manually adding executable path for webdrivers works, but webdriver_manager doesn't.

If I use

```
from webdrivermanager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

there is no `ChromeDriverManager().install()` option, only the `.download_and_install()`, which doesnt work.

Comment: py -m pip install webdriver-manager --upgrade. Then will get new version 3.86. Released: Apr 13, 2023

Comment: It was 3.8.6 version already. Re-installed it, but nothing changed.